# How to access mainnet data on Rinkeby?

Tags: testnets, testing, chaindata

I am writing a smart contract that uses the [CryptoPunks data smart contract](https://etherscan.io/address/0x16f5a35647d6f03d5d3da7b35409d65ba03af3b2#readContract).

This contract has a public read function `punkImageSvg()` that returns a string with the SVG of the punk in question. The data to generate these SVGs is not stored in the contract source, but was rather added to storage post-deploy.

My question is how I can call `punkImageSvg()` in a testing environment. On my local machine this is easy as I just fork mainnet with Hardhat. However, I cannot fork mainnet when I deploy to Rinkeby.

I could create my own `CryptoPunkData` contract on Rinkeby, but then I would have to populate it with Punk Data. However, I don’t know how to extract the data on the mainnet version and run it programmatically on the Rinkeby version. This approach would also take a lot of time as there are 10,000 Punks.

Of course the ideal solution would be if there is already a fully-populated Punk Data contract deployed to Rinkeby but if there is I cannot find one.

Overall looking for the best approach to using mainnet data on Rinkeby in a similar way that I use mainnet data locally via forking.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it via rinkeby, but you can do it on your own local chain using the mainnet forking tools like hardhat has: https://hardhat.org/hardhat-network/guides/mainnet-forking.html

Comment: The Hardhat forking works great, but some things are impossible to test locally like whether OpenSea correctly displays my NFT so I am not sure I can go straight from local development to mainnet deployment.

Do you know of any way to download all the transactions to a contract and then "play them back" on another? That would solve this problem. I can use Etherscan but it won't give me transaction payloads in bulk.

Comment: I think for that, you might be better off just spinning up openSea locally and pointing it to your localhost if you can...(I'd at least ask them if you can do that)

Answer (score 0):

For CryptoPunks Data specifically, I have created a Rinkeby contract mirror here: https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0xE1D8e86D222b8C0E479Eb9ee3d89415123Ac6387

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).